# How to determine equality of gene objects by gene name in Java

Tags: java

I have a gene class with the following constructor and properties

```
public class Gene implements Comparable<Gene> {
    String id;
    String name;

    //Constructor
    public Gene(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;

    }
```

In another class, I want to know which genes are similar between two sets and their similarity is based on the gene name.

```
        listOfAllGenes.retainAll(strain.getGenes());
```

Which method should I implement to compare two sets of genes by gene name please?

Thanks.

Comment: Except for the name of your data your question has nothing to do with bioinformatics. You may want to pick up a book on basic java and learn it though. Even if someone answers your question here, you most likely wouldn't understand it and just copying it doesn't teach you.

Comment: Also for your future reading, have a look at https://www.biostars.org/ the bioinformatics site in the stack exchange network.

Comment: Please define *compare two sets of genes by gene name*. What do you want to know about these sets? Your question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

add a getter method for name in your Gene class

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

then in another class use logic similar to this

```
ArrayList<Gene> matchingGenes = new ArrayList<>();
for (Gene gene1 : genelist1) {
    for (Gene gene2 : genelist2) {
        if gene1.getName().equals(gene2.getName) {
            matchingGenes.add(gene1);
            matchingGenes.add(gene2);
        }
    }
}
```

This will leave you with a list containing pairs of every Gene that shared a name with a Gene from the other list.